# I've got an error when running 'ng new angular-src' which 'You cannot use the new command inside an Angular CLI project.'

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

**package.json**

```
{     
 "name": "meanauthapp",    
  "version": "1.0.0",      
  "description": "mean stack application",      
  "main": "app.js",      
  "scripts": {    
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app"
  },    
  "dependencies": {    
    "express": "*",
    "mongoose": "*",
    "bcryptjs": "*",
    "cors": "*",
    "jsonwebtoken": "*",
    "body-parser": "*",
    "passport": "*",
    "passport-jwt": "*"
  },    
  "author": "ip",    
  "license": "ISC",    
  "devDependencies": {    
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by deleting 'package.json' file and 'node_module' folder from the application folder.